# How to backup/store between sqlite memory database and file database in Qt?

Tags: qt, sqlite, in-memory-database

What's the easiest way to backup/restore `sqlite` memory database to file database in `Qt`.

Comment: Why not use a plain file database to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to work with SQLite directly to do this. SQLite has an [Online Backup API](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html), the first example is backing up an in-memory database to a file database, so it should be possible to do what you need to do.

To get a `sqlite3*` database handle, get the [driver (`QSqlDatabase::driver`)](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#driver) from the database then get the [handle (`QSqlDriver::handle`)](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsqldriver.html#handle). The example code in the Qt docs shows how to cast the `QVariant` into a `sqlite3*` handle.

Comment: I think this way is not native enough. Because by using this, I should add `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` into project,when Qt already complies these two files into library. Isn't it make the program file large and bad by adding the same code into one file.

Comment: If you are using dynamic libraries, then you only need to include `sqlite3.h` and link against `sqlite3`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to link against `sqlite3` without using `sqlite3.dll`

Comment: You can either statically compile sqlite into your program by compiling in `sqlite3.c`, or dynamically link against `sqlite3.dll`, the code needs to be somewhere! The other option would be to link against the qtsql_sqlite driver, but that would only work if the sqlite symbols were exposed by the driver DLL (check using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) ).