# How to access sqlite3 directly from Qt without linking sqlite3.dll a second time

Tags: qt

I currently have `QT += sql` in my `.pro` file, but in addition to normal Qt access to sqlite3, I want to run the `sqlite3_backup_init()`, etc., so I need to use the driver directly.

I downloaded and `#include`d `"sqlite3.h"` but it's not linking properly as I suspected.
My program can do sqlite3 stuff using the Qt API, so clearly the sqlite3.dll code is loaded up somewhere in memory, but I'm not sure how to access it using the normal low-level sqlite3 API.  I'm able to get a handle to the underlying `sqlite3 *db` object fine.  I'm hesitant to try linking `sqlite3.dll` or `sqlite3.lib` again as this post suggests: [How to backup/store between sqlite memory database and file database in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726985/how-to-backup-store-between-sqlite-memory-database-and-file-database-in-qt)

So how can I reuse the already-linked sqlite3 machinery using low level API?

QT5, MSVC

Comment: Why don't you follow what they point out in the comments: you must link the .dll? Can you show the .pro?

Comment: Yes that's what I wound up doing.  Actually first I just added the giant sqlite3.c file to my project (7-8 MB I think), and then swapped that out for the precompiled .dll (2-3 MB I think) as it is smaller than the source, so it won't clog up my .git folder as much.  Yes, binaries in git.